# Equating a list to the function of another list

Tags: python

At the moment, I have a piece of code with lots of lists equal to the function of another list, embedded in a loop in Python:

```
Power = [x,y,z]
Force = []
for i in range(len(Power)):
    Force.append(((function(Power[i])-0.5))/slope)
```

I would like to simplify it down to:

```
Force = function(Power[i])-0.5))/slope)
```

but it doesn't work. It does however work when there's no function, just a simple relationship. Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
Force = [(function(x)-0.5)/slope for x in Power]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the most concise / simplest way to do this is via list comprehension, in particular you can do something as follows:

```
Force = [(function(Power[i])-0.5)/slope for i in range(len(Power))]
```

Very similar to what you have already done earlier, but comes in a nice and simple one line expression.